# How to find min cost for element selection from a sequence of adjacent pairs

Tags: python, algorithm, dynamic-programming

Given an array of integers (with at least two elements), I need to choose at least one element of each adjacent pair of elements in the array in a way that costs me the least. Then, return the cost and elements chosen.
For example,

```
[50, 30, 40, 60, 10, 30, 10]
```

We choose 30 for the pair (50, 30), and for the pair (30, 40). Then we choose 40 for the pair (40, 60) and 10 for the pairs (60, 10), (10, 30). Lastly, 10 for the pair (30, 10). So we got 30 + 40 + 10 + 10 = 90.

Another example,

```
[60, 100, 70]
```

There are two possible selections: [60, 70] or [100]. But, the optimal solution would be [100] for a total of 100, which is less than 60 + 70. So, the algorithm should choose 100.

My issue is that I only succeeded in making a code that returns the lowest cost without saving the elements used.

**My Code in Python**

```
arr = [50, 30, 40, 60, 10, 30, 10]
min_sum = [0] * len(arr)
min_sum[0] = arr[0]
min_sum[1] = arr[1]

for i in range(2, len(arr)):
    choice1 = min_sum[i-1] + arr[i]
    choice2 = min_sum[i-2] + arr[i]
    min_sum[i] = min(choice1, choice2)

res = min(min_sum[-1], min_sum[-2])
print(res)
```

Comment: Would `from itertools import pairwise; selection = list(map(min,pairwise(arr))); print(selection)` do what you want?

Comment: @Stef it returns [30, 30, 40, 10, 10, 10] not [30, 40, 10, 10]

Comment: Sorry but why does is desired result `[30, 40, 10, 10]`? why does 30 appear only once and 10 only twice? To me it looks like `[30, 30, 40, 10, 10, 10]` should be the correct result, but in your comment you complain about it. Could you explain your logic?

Comment: @Elerium115 It looks like if you choose the same element (index) twice, you only report it once. 10 is reported twice because they are two different 10s.

Comment: Hi. Building on @Elerium115 's comment: could you please clarify what the expected result would be if the input array is `[60, 100, 70]`? Do you want output `[60, 70]`, or do you want output `[100]`?

Comment: @n.m.couldbeanAI That's a reasonable and likely interpretation, and would explain the dynamic-programming tag, but a clarification from the OP would be welcome

Comment: It's indeed unclear. The question says "a code that returns the lowest cost"  which would imply 100. But in the explanation the OP says "We choose 30 for the pair (50, 30)". If you have only seen (50, 30) you cannot yet determine that 30 is the best option, unless the lowest cost means the lowest cost of each pair, not the global minimum cost.  Also the question doesn't specify anywhere that an element must be taken only once, hence my question about how `[30, 40, 10, 10]` is the desired output

Comment: @stef if the input array is [60, 100, 70] then the answer would be 100 since for both (60, 100) and (100, 70) one element was chosen and the cost is lower than choosing both 60 and 70.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling `cost(i)` the cost of the optimal solution when considering the array up to element `i` included only, there is a simple recurrence formula for this problem:

```
cost(i) = min(
    arr[i] + cost(i-1),
    arr[i-1] + cost(i-2),
)
```

For instance, the cost for array [50, 30, 40, 60, 10, 30, 10] is the minimum of

```
10 + cost for [50, 30, 40, 60, 10, 30]
30 + cost for [50, 30, 40, 60, 10]
```

The base cases for this recurrence are:

```
cost(0) = 0
cost(1) = 0
cost(2) = min(arr[0],arr[1])
```

This recurrence relation leads to a simple iterative code:

```py
def cost(a):
    if len(a) <= 1:
        return 0
    elif len(a) == 2:
        return min(a)
    cost_iminus2 = 0
    cost_iminus1 = min(a[:2])
    for i in range(2,len(a)):
        cost_i = min(
            arr[i] + cost_iminus1,
            arr[i-1] + cost_iminus2,
        )
        cost_iminus2, cost_iminus1 = cost_iminus1, cost_i
    return cost_i
```

You can easily amend this code to also remember which elements were used in the sum:

```py
def selection(a):
    if len(a) < 2:
        return 0, []
    elif len(a) == 2:
        return min(a), [min(a)]
    cost_iminus2, selection_iminus2 = 0, []
    cost_iminus1, selection_iminus1 = min(a[:2]), [min(a[:2])]
    for i in range(2,len(a)):
        cost_i = min(
            a[i] + cost_iminus1,
            a[i-1] + cost_iminus2,
        )
        if cost_i == a[i] + cost_iminus1:
            selection_i = [*selection_iminus1, a[i]] # need to copy
        elif cost_i == a[i-1] + cost_iminus2:
            selection_i = selection_iminus2 # no need to copy
            selection_i.append(a[i-1])
        else:
            raise ValueError("unreachable branch")
        cost_iminus2, cost_iminus1 = cost_iminus1, cost_i
        selection_iminus2, selection_iminus1 = selection_iminus1, selection_i
    return cost_i, selection_i
```

Output:

```
>>> selection([50, 30, 40, 60, 10, 30, 10])
(90, [30, 40, 10, 10])
>>> selection([60,100,70])
(100, [100])
```

Comment: "I need to choose at least one element of each adjacent pair of elements" that includes (40, 60)

Comment: @NitaStack Now it should be alright

Comment: @NitaStack My main mistake was the initialisation case. If `len(a)` is 0 or 1, the output should be cost 0 and empty selection, since there are no pairs that need to be chosen from.

Comment: Note that because of `selection_i = [*selection_iminus1, a[i]]` this takes quadratic time instead of linear time. It's possible to be a little bit more astute with this bookkeeping and avoid making the copy, at the cost of slightly less easy-to-read code.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you can save the indices instead of elements, then recreate the desired output by these indices:

```py
lst = [50, 30, 40, 60, 10, 30, 10]

out = []
for i in range(len(lst) - 1):
    mn = min(i, i + 1, key=lambda k: lst[k])
    if not out or mn != out[-1]:
        out.append(mn)

out = [lst[i] for i in out]
print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[30, 40, 10, 10]
```

Comment: You could also use `key=lst.__getitem__` to avoid an unnecessary lambda function. Arguably, it's more readable in your way though.

Comment: There's a bit of interpretation with the OP's question, but from what I understand, this algorithm does not always give the optimal answer. Consider `[60, 100, 70]`. Your algorithm would output `[60, 70]` for a total of 130, because 60 is less than 100 and 70 is less than 100. But the optimal solution would be `[100]` for a total of 100, which is less than 130.

Comment: @Stef But that's other kind of problem (optimization). I let OP to clarify this.

Comment: @stef yes, the optimal solution would be [100] and that should be the chosen element.

Answer (score 0):

Here is other ways that u can take look. I added case when have one left element. in your code u going to get the same sum once ur list is **[50, 30, 40, 60, 10, 30, 10,10]** but u have extra one element. In this example your code will have sum as 90 but it should be 100. So, I added this part to avoid missing that.

```
if l==len(arr)-1: #Check if there is only one element left to check
    res.append(arr[l])
```

Final code should be like that.

```
arr = [50, 30, 40, 60, 10, 30, 10]


l = 0
r = 1
res = []
while r<len(arr):
    min_value = min(arr[l],arr[r])
    res.append(min_value)
    print(min_value)

    if min_value==arr[r]: 
        l+=2
        if l==len(arr)-1 and r != len(arr)-1: #Check if there is only one element left to check
            res.append(arr[l])
        r+=2
        
    else:
        l+=1
        r+=1
    

print(res,sum(res))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = [50, 30, 40, 60, 10, 30, 10]  

my_set: set = set(i if elem[0] <= elem[1] else i + 1 for i, elem in enumerate(zip(arr[:-1], arr[1:])))  

# using lists
my_list: list[int] = [arr[i] for i in my_set]  
print(my_list)  # the values from the initial list
print(sum(my_list))  # sum of values from the initial list

# using dictionaries
my_dict: dict = {i: arr[i] for i in my_set}  
print(list(my_dict.values()))  # the values from the initial list
print(sum(list(my_dict.values())))  # sum of values from the initial list
```